# What does it mean: "Aktueller Stand nur in Pergamon"?

Tags: translation, collocation

I have found this expression in a BASF document named Checklist for externals.

Here is the full phrase - 'Aktueller Stand nur im Pergamon – Ausdruck/Kopie unterliegt NICHT dem Änderungsdienst!', which is located at the bottom of the document, and actually is just a technical information. But why Pergamon? what it means?
I've searched a lot and have three weak answers:

1. Ancient city
2. It is a name of printing paper
3. Pergamon Press.

Comment: Hi, sorry for a clerical error. It should read 'BASF document'. Basf is a chemical company.

Comment: Pergamon could be the name of some software where documents are kept.

Comment: Great idea, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Pergamon" is the name of a document management system of a (former) company "Ainea AG".

I assume that the company "Ainea AG" no longer exists because the web site
http://ainea-ag.de
is currently unreachable and the last normal snapshot in the web archive dates from 2013.
http://web.archive.org/web/20131029044231/http://www.ainea-ag.de/
Newer snapshots show placeholder pages only.

I have seen similar notes like "Ausdruck/Kopie unterliegt NICHT dem Änderungsdienst!" in (printed or PDF) documents that are stored in a document management system at the responsible company/organization.

Comment: Hi, well done. Thank you. You version really makes sense in this context.

Answer (score 3):

Bodo has already given a precise answer. But I think it is clear - without knowing the internal organisation of BASF - that in a phrase like "Aktueller Stand nur im Pergamon – Ausdruck/Kopie unterliegt NICHT dem Änderungsdienst!" which is used in the context of *documents* the word **Pergamon** can only refer to an (electronic)  [document management system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_management_system) (abbreviated DMS).

The part "Ausdruck/Kopie unterliegt NICHT dem Änderungsdienst" means that if you have a print version of a document (for example in conventional paper files), then you cannot be sure that it has the current status. The complete version history of a certain document is available only in the DMS.

By the way, the word *Pergamon* refers to the well-known [ancient Greek city](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pergamon). Quotation:

> The Library of Pergamon was renowned as second only to the Library of Alexandria. Pergamon was also a flourishing center for the production of parchment (the word itself, a corruption of pergamenos, meaning "from Pergamon"), which had been used in Asia Minor long before the rise of the city. The story that parchment was invented by the Pergamenes because the Ptolemies in Alexandria had a monopoly on papyrus production is not true.

Note that the German word for *parchment* is *Pergament*.